# How to show my BLE device battery percentage on iPhone battery app?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am developing an iOS app for non apple wearable device which communicates through BLE technology. I got the battery percentage from the BLE device though some characteristic id, but is there any way to display that percentage on iPhone's battery app? Also is there any way to show battery low notification when the app is closed?